# XSSFCellStyle not working in LibreOffice Calc Ubuntu

Tags: java, excel, ubuntu, apache-poi, libreoffice-calc

I am using apache poi 3.9 to create excel sheet but border not showing in LibreOffice Calc in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. If I open same sheet in windows everything if just fine. What changes need to be done in following code

```
private XSSFCellStyle getCommomCellStyle(XSSFWorkbook workbook) {
        XSSFCellStyle cellStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
        cellStyle.setAlignment(XSSFCellStyle.ALIGN_LEFT);
        cellStyle.setVerticalAlignment(XSSFCellStyle.VERTICAL_CENTER);
        cellStyle.setBorderBottom(XSSFCellStyle.BORDER_THIN);
        cellStyle.setBorderTop(XSSFCellStyle.BORDER_THIN);
        cellStyle.setBorderRight(XSSFCellStyle.BORDER_THIN);
        cellStyle.setBorderLeft(XSSFCellStyle.BORDER_THIN);
        cellStyle.setWrapText(true);
        Font font = workbook.createFont();
        font.setFontName("Arial");
        font.setFontHeightInPoints((short)10);
        //      font.setBoldweight(XSSFFont.BOLDWEIGHT_BOLD);
        cellStyle.setFont(font);
        return cellStyle;
    }
```

Here you can see am not getting right border and bottom border

> bottom border of remark is actually top border of next cell

Please suggest how can I solve this issue.

[image]

Comment: The format is okay in LibreOffice in Windows and only wrong in LibreOffice in Ubuntu?

Comment: In window am opening in Microsoft office and its working fine

Comment: color issue is solved by using `cellStyle.setFillForegroundColor(new XSSFColor(java.awt.Color.YELLOW));` but unable to solve border issue.

Comment: Why are you using an old version of Apache POI? What happens when you upgrade?

Comment: Same issue even by using poi 3.16